# Horizontal scroll in UIWebView and vertical scroll in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have a UITableView with cells. One of the cells has a full size UIWebView.
On the web view I want ONLY to enable horizontal scroll (like coverflow).
I can do that with this ansawer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575036/406055

But: Then the UIWebView intercepts the vertical scroll (thus without performing it). I want the vertical scroll gesture to affect the tableview, not the web view.

The idea I have is to either overlay the web view with a UIView and add gesture recognizers and then pass the gesture on to the UIWebView only if it is horizontal.

But any other suggestions is welcome too.