# Nil drawable for layer <MetalLayer: 0x28218ed50> Slows Down UITableView Reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I run my app in Device Then I am getting this error for reloading my TableView. And it takes unto 20Sec for reloading Data.

But when I run my app in Simulator then there is not error and loading is performed in less than 5sec.

Comment: kindly add cellforRowAtIndexPath and UItableViewCell class code here

Comment: Hi, sorry I am unable to class code here bcoz of company policies. But I will briefly explain to you what I am doing to suggest to you. In UITableView I am showing  HTML String in UITextView and for showing full content. After that, I am reframing the above UITextView on its Cell and other UIView(which contain UIButton and UIlabel) below the UITextView. And now on run time I am getting this issue some time my Table loading within 5secs when there is not Drawable error but when I got the drawable error to take up to 20sec to load.

Comment: first identify the reason of delay. i think  UITextView will be reason in your cases, can you please comment the UITextView code and check the app performance. if UITextView is the reason then put the heavy performance task in background if possible.

Comment: Hi, Thanks yes you are right I have found my textView is the problem. So, I have replace it with UIWebView. But now now my TableView vertical scrolling is stucks even I have done. - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    
    [webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(webView.scrollView.contentSize.width,0)];
 }.        Please Suggest me what to do to avoid scrolling issue.

Comment: check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the scrolling of webview to set.

like :

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = false 
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Comment: showing error  Expression is not assignable in scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0

Comment: Thanks, dear but this code will enabled both horizontal and vertical scrolling but I need horizontal scrolling.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099108/how-do-i-enable-horizontal-scrolling-and-disable-vertical-scrolling-in-uiwebview/12575036

Comment: yes, thanks. I have simply set  [webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.frame.size.height.)];   in webViewDidFinish.